# Error reading multiple files with multiple sheets in r

Tags: r, readxl

I would like to read more than one file with more than one sheet each one in a single dataset in R. I have been using this code but now it doesn't work any more. Is there a solution for the error I get?

Code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(fs)
library(readxl)

path <- ("Z:/mypath")

# Create function specifing to skip 9 rows 
read_multiple_excel <- function(path) {
  path %>%
    excel_sheets() %>%
    set_names() %>%
  map_df(read_excel, path = path, skip = 9, .id = "name")
}

# joining all data.frames
data_df <- dir_ls(regexp = "xlsx") %>%
  purrr::map_df(read_multiple_excel) %>%
  mutate(ID = row_number())
```

When I run the code it gives me this error:

> Error in `dplyr::bind_rows()`:
> ! Can't combine `Hoja1$...4`  and `Feuil1$...4` .
> Backtrace:
>
> 1. ... %>% mutate(ID = row_number())
> 2. purrr::map_df(., read_excel, path = path, skip = 9, .id = "name")
> 3. dplyr::bind_rows(res, .id = .id)
> 4. vctrs::vec_rbind(!!!dots, .names_to = .id)

The technique I use comes from https://dominicroye.github.io/es/2019/importar-varias-hojas-excel-en-r/

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Did it stop working because you added more xlsx files to the folder?  Maybe the fourth columns are incompatible types

Comment: From the error message I would guess that your sheets are read with different data types, i.e. the fourth column in sheet `Hoja1` has a different type then for sheet `Feuil1`. And bind_rows will complain about that. One possible fix would be to set the data types via the `col_types` argument instead of relying on the default guess.

Comment: @MichaelDewar No, all the files are the same. A colleague is running the same code with the same files and does not get this error

Comment: @stefan where can I put the `col_types` argument in the code?

Comment: `col_types` is an argument of `read_excel` so in your code something like `map_df(read_excel, path = path, skip = 9, col_types = ....., .id = "name")`.

Comment: Perhaps you and your colleague are using different versions of packages.  An update might have made the bind_rows more strict than before.  You should probably try to find which columns/sheets/files have different type and make sure that coercing them to the same thing is really what you want.